# Need access to job launcher parameters when creating job

Tags: spring-batch

I am invoking my batch service via the command line and supply a few parameters for the job. I need access to these parameters when create the job as I need to look up data from the db for a 'site name' that is supplied as a parameter and dynamically create multiple steps. The issue is in the 'createJob' method. I've hard coded the site id currently but there is an exception for the itemizedReader method:

```
Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.itemizedReader' defined in billing.BillingConfig: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'itemizedReader' parameter 1: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String]
```

Spring configuration

```
package billing;

import billing.components.AspiviaFieldSetter;
import billing.components.AspiviaPrepStatementSetter;
import billing.components.SummaryProcessor;
import billing.mapper.ItemizedCostingMapper;
import billing.model.BillingItem;
import billing.model.ItemizedCosting;
import billing.tasklet.SummaryOutputTasklet;
import billing.batch.common.AppProps;
import billing.batch.common.SqlConst;
import billing.batch.common.model.ItemizedPartner;
import billing.batch.common.repo.PartnerBillingRepo;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepScope;
import org.springframework.batch.core.job.builder.SimpleJobBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FieldExtractor;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;

@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"billing", "billing.batch.common"})
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@PropertySource("classpath:/app.properties")
public class BillingConfig {

    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Autowired
    private AppProps appProps;

    @Autowired
    private PartnerBillingRepo billingRepo;

    @Bean
    @Profile("prod")
    public DataSource datasource() {
        final HikariConfig cfg = new HikariConfig();
        cfg.setJdbcUrl(appProps.getPartnerBillingUrl());
        cfg.setUsername(appProps.getPartnerBillingUsername());
        cfg.setPassword(appProps.getPartnerBillingPassword());
        cfg.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", appProps.getCachePrepStatements());
        cfg.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", appProps.getPrepStatementCacheSize());
        cfg.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", appProps.getPrepStatementCacheSqlLimit());

        HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource(cfg);

        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate template(DataSource ds) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(ds);
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemReader billingFileReader(@Value("#{jobParameters['input.file']}") String inputFile) {
        DefaultLineMapper lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper();
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new BillingFieldSetter());
        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer());

        FlatFileItemReader reader = new FlatFileItemReader();
        reader.setLineMapper(lineMapper);
        reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(inputFile));

        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter BillingWriter(DataSource ds, BillingPrepStatementSetter setter) {
        JdbcBatchItemWriter writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter();
        writer.setDataSource(ds);
        writer.setItemPreparedStatementSetter(setter);
        writer.setSql(SqlConst.INSERT_INTO_BILLING);

        return writer;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public BillingPrepStatementSetter prepStatementSetter() {
        return new BillingPrepStatementSetter();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public SummaryProcessor summaryProc() {
        return new SummaryProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public SummaryOutputTasklet summaryTask() {
        return new SummaryOutputTasklet();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemReader<ItemizedCosting> itemizedReader(@Value("#{jobParameters['site.id']}") Integer siteId, String accountCodes,
            @Value("#{jobParameter['start.date']") String startDate, @Value("#{jobParameters['end.date']") String endDate) {

        JdbcCursorItemReader reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader();
        reader.setDataSource(datasource());
        reader.setSql(SqlConst.SELECT_ITEMIZED_BILLING_FOR_ACCOUNT_CODES);
        reader.setRowMapper(new ItemizedCostingMapper());
        reader.setPreparedStatementSetter((ps) -> {
            try {
                SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

                ps.setTimestamp(0, new Timestamp(formatter.parse(startDate).getTime()));
                ps.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(formatter.parse(endDate).getTime()));
            } catch (Exception err) {
                LOG.error("Unable to parse dates, start: {} end: {}", startDate, endDate);
            }
            ps.setString(2, accountCodes);
            ps.setInt(3, siteId);
        });

        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemWriter<ItemizedCosting> itemizedWriter(@Value("start.date") String startDate,
            String partnerName) {

        DelimitedLineAggregator lineAgg = new DelimitedLineAggregator();
        FieldExtractor<ItemizedCosting> extractor = (f) -> {
            Object[] output = new Object[9];
            output[0] = f.getExtension();
            output[1] = f.getPbxCallTime();
            output[2] = f.getDuration();
            output[3] = f.getAccountCode();
            output[4] = f.getDigits();
            output[5] = f.getCost();
            output[6] = f.getDestination();
            output[7] = f.getCarrier();
            output[8] = f.getAttribute();

            return output;
        };
        lineAgg.setFieldExtractor(extractor);

        Timestamp start = null;

        try {
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

            start = new Timestamp(formatter.parse(startDate).getTime());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Unable to parse date: {}", startDate);
        }

        FlatFileItemWriter<ItemizedCosting> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
        writer.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        writer.setLineAggregator(lineAgg);
        writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource(String.format("%s/%2$tY-%2$tm_%s_",
                appProps.getItemizedBillingOutputPath(), start, partnerName)));

        return writer;
    }

    @Bean
    public Job createJob(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilder, StepBuilderFactory stepBuilders, DataSource ds, FlatFileItemReader reader)
            throws Exception {
        Step findSiteIdStep = stepBuilders.get("find.site.id").tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
            String siteName
                    = (String) chunkContext.getStepContext().getJobParameters().get(BillingConst.PARAM_SITE);

            Integer siteId = billingRepo.findSiteIdByName(siteName);

            chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().put(
                    BillingConst.SITE_ID, siteId);

            return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
        }).build();

        Step processFileStep = stepBuilders.get("process.file").<BillingItem, BillingItem>chunk(appProps.getChunkSize())
                .reader(reader)
                .processor(summaryProc())
                .writer(aspiviaWriter(ds, prepStatementSetter())).build();

        Step outputSummary = stepBuilders.get("output.summary").tasklet(summaryTask()).build();

        SimpleJobBuilder builder = jobBuilder.get("process.aspivia").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(findSiteIdStep)
                .next(processFileStep)
                .next(outputSummary);

        List<ItemizedPartner> partners = billingRepo.findPartnersForSite("CPT");
        Integer siteId = billingRepo.findSiteIdByName("CPT");

        Map<String, String> partnerAccCodes = new HashMap<>();

        partners.stream().forEach(i -> {
            if (!partnerAccCodes.containsKey(i.getPartnerName())) {
                partnerAccCodes.put(i.getPartnerName(), "");
            }

            String accCodes = partnerAccCodes.get(i.getPartnerName());
            accCodes += i.getAccountCode().toString() + ", ";

            partnerAccCodes.put(i.getPartnerName(), accCodes);
        });

        partnerAccCodes.forEach((k, v) -> {
            Step itemizedReport = stepBuilders.get("itemized." + k).<ItemizedCosting, ItemizedCosting>chunk(appProps.getChunkSize())
                    .reader(itemizedReader(siteId, v, null, null))
                    .writer(itemizedWriter(null, k)).build();

            builder.next(itemizedReport);
        });

        return builder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propCfg() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource datasource) {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(datasource);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the lifecycle on how spring batch works. If the bean is decorated for the @StepScope the job parameters are only available once it is launched.

```
    final Job loadAspiviaDataJob = context.getBean(Job.class);
    final JobLauncher launcher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);

    JobParametersBuilder paramBuilder = new JobParametersBuilder();
    paramBuilder.addString(AspiviaConst.PARAM_INPUT_FILE, inputFile);
    paramBuilder.addString(AspiviaConst.PARAM_SITE, site);
    paramBuilder.addString(AspiviaConst.PARAM_OUTPUT_FILE_PATH, summaryFile);
```

JobExecution runStatus = launcher.run(loadAspiviaDataJob, paramBuilder.toJobParameters());

In the above code same we retrieve the *Job* which is setup via the *createJob* bean method in my configuration. The job parameters are not available.

What I have done to get access to the values I need is as follows:

- Added an extra @PropertySource("classpath:cli-runtime.properties")
- The Application.java that launches the spring batch job will save the properties we need to cli-runtime.properties. When the Job is created in the @Configuration class the values will be loaded from the property file and I can create the additional steps in the job I require